# How to insert data from list array to datagridview?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I need to insert data from array to a `DataGridView`, but when I give handle to `DataGridView` from list, everything what I get is count of elements in array.

```
public static class Globalne
{
   public static List<string> Mena = new List<string>();
   public static string[] stringy = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
}
```

This is the program

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Name";
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Surname";
    dataGridView1.DataSource =  Globalne.stringy;
}
```

Comment: You defined 3 columns to show a string array which can not bind to any of those columns. What do you expect? What are you going to do?

Comment: I want insert array list to one column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem, consider these notes:

- To bind `DataGridView` to an array of string, you should shape the array to a `List` containing a property.
- Each column of the `DataGridView` will show value of the property of the `DataSource` which have the same property name as the column's `DataPropertyName`.

**Example**

```
string[] stringy = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("C1", "Header 1");
dataGridView1.Columns["C1"].DataPropertyName = "Property1";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("C2", "Header 2");
dataGridView1.DataSource = stringy.Select(x => new { Property1 = x }).ToList();
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted ! Thank you so much !

Comment: In general I recommend you to use a `BindingList<T>` or a `DataTable` for editing data in `DataGridView` rather that such array.

Comment: But how can I make that same with next column and with another list array ? When I try something everything what I get is rewrite first column, what is otherwise in last line ?

Comment: Each column of the `DataGridView` will show value of the property of the `DataSource` which have the same property name as the column's `DataPropertyName`. For example, for the second column, set it's data property name to `Property2` and then when shaping the string list, select ` new { Property2 = x }`. That's why I told you it's better to use `BindingList<T>` or `DataTable` rather than array.